# Open Email Attachments File

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have open attachments file using following code

```
Sub Test()
Dim path As String
Dim msgFile As String

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path + "\"

file = path & "\*.msg"

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.mailitem
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(file)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Application.User

    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

But

Email attachments file was not open.

How to Open Email Attachments File in Macro?

Comment: Get rid of that `On Error Resume Next`, which is hiding any potential errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `Application` class from the Excel object model doesn't provide the `User` property. Instead, you could use the `UserName` property which returns the name of the current user.

```
MsgBox "Current user is " & Application.UserName
```

The `MailItem.To` property returns or sets a semicolon-delimited string list of display names for the `To` recipients for the Outlook item. But I would suggest using the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection which should be used to modify the `To` property.